Use of トランク: Translation suggests "suitcase" but Japanese suggests "car trunk"
This comes from episode 1 of the anime Black Lagoon where the protagonist joins a crew of smugglers and asks one of the newer members how they wound up in the crew. He [A] responds and another more seasoned crew member [B] says that he isn't experienced enough to be storytelling:

[A]火遊びが元でマフィアと ＦＢＩ を同時に怒らせちゃってねそれで …
[B]トランクに重し代わりに詰められるとこを ― あたしが助けたってわけよ
クソ話はよしなよベニー 昔話するほど年は食ってねえ
[A]I was fooling around and pissed off the
Mafia and the FBI. Then...
[B]I saved his ass before he was thrown
overboard in a suitcase.
Stop the worthless storytelling. You're not
old enough to be reminiscing about the past. (shows translation)

It is true that like "trunk" in English トランク can refer both to a car trunk and a suitcase. However, there is no mention of being thrown "overboard", so that makes the interpretation of suitcase less likely. Also, a key part is I am not sure how 重し is being used here. It seems to mostly be used when talking about weighing down pickled vegetables. Pretty certain this is not talking about a suitcase then, but I also am not sure what is used to "weigh down" a car trunk either.
What image is this phrase really conquering up?

Hiding a body in a suitcase or a drum and sinking it is recognized (at least by Japanese speakers) as a method used by criminal syndicates to eliminate someone without a trace. The English version seems more "direct", but they essentially refer to the same thing.

That makes sense because before I was thinking of "black bagging" which would instead involve a car trunk.

First, おもし is a weight (like paperweight). So it means the person was put in a suitcase so that the suitcase would sink.
Regarding overboard, what is meant is that the suitcase containing the person (as a weight) was about to be thrown overboard.
